# Graph evolution of quantile non-linear coefficient: can it be done with grqreg? Other options?

Tags: stata, quantile, non-linear-regression, coefplot

I have the following model:

**Y_{it} = alpha_i + B1*weight_{it} + B2*Dummy_Foreign_{i} + B3*(weight*Dummy_Foreign)_ {it} + e_{it}**

and I am interested on the effect on Y of weight for foreign cars and to graph the evolution of the relevant coefficient across quantiles, with the respective standard errors. That is, I need to see the evolution of the coefficients (B1+ B3). I know this is a non-linear effect, and would require some sort of delta method to obtain the variance-covariance matrix to obtain the standard error of (B1+B3).

Before I delve into writing a program that attempts to do this, I thought I would try and ask if there is a way of doing it with grqreg. If this is not possible with grqreg, would someone please guide me into how they would start writing a code that computes the proper standard errors, and graphs the quantile coefficient.

For a cross section example of what I am trying to do, please see code below.

1. I use grqred to generate the evolution of the separate coefficients (but I need the joint one)-- One graph for the evolution of (B1+B3) with it's respective standard errors.

Thanks. [image: Effect of weight and weight interacted with foreign dummy variable.]

(I am using Stata 14.1 on Windows 10):

```
clear
sysuse auto
set scheme s1color

gen gptm = 1000/mpg
label var gptm "gallons / 1000 miles"

gen weight_foreign= weight*foreign
label var weight_foreign "Interaction weight and foreign car"

qreg gptm weight foreign weight_foreign , q(.5) 
grqreg  weight weight_foreign , ci ols olsci reps(40)  

*** Question 1: How to constuct the plot of the coefficient of interest?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second question is off-topic here since it is statistical. Try the CV SE site or Statalist.

Here's how you might do (1) in a cross section, using `margins` and `marginsplot`:

```
clear
set more off
sysuse auto
set scheme s1color
gen gptm = 1000/mpg
label var gptm "gallons / 1000 miles"
sqreg gptm c.weight##i.foreign, q(10 25 50 75 95) reps(500) coefl
margins, dydx(weight) predict(outcome(q10)) predict(outcome(q25)) predict(outcome(q50)) predict(outcome(q75)) predict(outcome(q95)) at(foreign=(0 1)) 
marginsplot, xdimension(_predict) xtitle("Quantile") ///
legend(label(1 "Domestic") label(2 "Foreign")) ///
xlabel(none) xlabel(1 "Q10" 2 "Q25" 3 "Q50" 4 "Q75" 5 "Q95", add) ///
title("Marginal Effect of Weight By Origin") ///
ytitle("GPTM")
```

This produces a graph like this:

[image]

I didn't recast the CI here since it would look cluttered, but that would make it look more like your graph. Just add `recastci(rarea)` to the options.

Unfortunately, none of the *panel* quantile regression commands play nice with factor variables and `margins`. But we can hack something together. First, you can calculate the sums of coefficients with `nlcom` (instead of more natural `lincom`, which the lacks the `post` option), store them, and use Ben Jann's `coefplot` to graph them. Here's a toy example to give you the main idea where we will look at the effect of tenure for union members:

```
set more off
estimates clear
webuse nlswork, clear
gen tXu = tenure*union
local quantiles 1 5 10 25 50 75 90 95 99    // K quantiles that you care about
local models ""                             // names of K quantile models for coefplot to graph 
local xlabel ""                             // for x-axis labels
local j=1                                   // counter for quantiles
foreach q of numlist `quantiles' {
    qregpd ln_wage tenure union tXu, id(idcode) fix(year) quantile(`q')
    nlcom (me_tu:_b[tenure]+_b[tXu]), post
    estimates store me_tu`q'
    local models `"`models' me_tu`q' || "'
    local xlabel `"`xlabel' `j++' "Q{sub:`q'}""'
}
di "`models'
di `"`xlabel'"'
coefplot `models' /// 
, vertical bycoefs rescale(100) ///
xlab(none) xlabel(`xlabel', add) ///
title("Marginal Effect of Tenure for Union Members On Each Conditional Quantile Q{sub:{&tau}}", size(medsmall)) ///
ytitle("Wage Change in Percent" "") yline(0) ciopts(recast(rcap))
```

This makes a dromedary curve, which suggests that the effect of tenure is larger in the middle of the wage distribution than at the tails:

[image]